# How to simulate the quantum measurement of a quantum state in Quantum Image

Tags: quantum-computing, quantum-information, image-processing

I'm trying to implement (simulate) the Novel Enhanced Quantum Representation ([NEQR](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11128-013-0567-z)), which is one of the quantum image representation models, but i'm stuck in the measurement part. In other words i don't know how to retrieve the original image from the quantum state.

The image is represented by the following formula (this is the final form after preparation):
$$ 
\left| \psi \right\rangle = \frac{1}{2^n} 
\displaystyle\sum_{Y=0}^{2^n -1} \displaystyle\sum_{X=0}^{2^n-1} \left| f(Y,X) \right\rangle \left| YX \right\rangle
$$

Now, assume that i have a 2 x 2 image and the color of each pixel is 2 bit only, the position -> color cobinations are as follow:

```
YX -> color
00 -> 11
01 -> 00
10 -> 01
11 -> 00
```

The image or the final state which is composed of two entangled qubit sequences (color and position) should be a 16 x 1 column vector indexed by binary representation from 0 to 15 (e.g. 0000, 0001, ... 1111) and the value of 0001 will be 1 because color 00 is located in position 01.

The measurement is as follow:

> During image retrieval from the quantum image, every pixel should be recovered
>   individually. The following operations have been devised to retrieve pixel from a
>   $$ 2^n × 2^n $$  quantum image.

How to perform measurement on the quantum state to retrieve the original image. In other words how to construct the matrix that when i multiply it with the state i retrieve the original image, but how to do that according to Quantum Operations ?

Please help to to solve this issue or guide me to the correct path. 
I didn't add all equations because i don't know if that is legal so please look for them in the paper.